# Path string from std::vector`

Tags: c++, algorithm, iterator, stdvector, stdstring

I have a vector of char which looks something like

```
C:/Users/person/Desktop/Albedo.pngC:/Users/person/Desktop/Metallic.pngC:/Users/person/Desktop/Noice.pngC:/Users/person/Desktop/AO.png
```

How do I split the vector to individual paths?
That is, I want to have

```cpp
std::string path1; // = C:/Users/person/Desktop/Albedo.png;
std::string path2; // = C:/Users/person/Desktop/Metallic.png;
std::string path3; // = C:/Users/person/Desktop/Noice.png;
std::string path4; // = C:/Users/person/Desktop/AO.png;
```

Any idea how can I do that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Use winapi’s `splitpath` and/or `std::getline`.

Comment: Will `std::getline` help? I don't think so. I will take a look at Winapi’s `splitpath`, thanks!

Comment: You could also check `<filesystem>`.

Comment: Unless there is a fixed number of "individual paths", extract a `std::vector<std::string>`, not distinct variables.  Anyway, the start of each string is indicated by presence of a triplet consisting of a letter (the drive), followed by a `':'` then a `'/'`.  Work out how to loop through the vector searching for that triplet, and extract characters between two triplets to a string.  Also, some systems (e.g. windows) also use a `'\'` (which must be delimited in `char` or string literals) as a path separator.   No, I'm not going to write code - you need to apply some effort to solve YOUR problem

Comment: I didn’t see the full string - I’m on a phone. Please disregard my comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example a straightforward approach provided that each path in the vector has the extension `.png` can look for example the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

int main() 
{
    const char *s ="C:/Users/person/Desktop/Albedo.png"
                   "C:/Users/person/Desktop/Metallic.png"
                   "C:/Users/person/Desktop/Noice.png"
                   "C:/Users/person/Desktop/AO.png";
    std::vector<char> v( s, s + std::strlen( s ) );
    
    std::vector<std::string> paths;
    const char *ext = ".png";
    size_t n = std::strlen( ext );
    
    for ( auto first = std::begin( v ), last = std::end( v ), it = first;
          ( it = std::search( first, last, ext, ext + n ) ) != last;
          first = it
        )
    {
        std::advance( it, n );
        paths.push_back( { first, it } );
    }         
    
    for ( const auto &path : paths )
    {
        std::cout << path << '\n';
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
C:/Users/person/Desktop/Albedo.png
C:/Users/person/Desktop/Metallic.png
C:/Users/person/Desktop/Noice.png
C:/Users/person/Desktop/AO.png
```

Comment: Nice, thank you very much! Works like a charm! Do you know of any way to make this extension independent? I am thinking of splitting with `C:/` but then it would make it platform dependent :(

Comment: @FahimFuad I did not think yet about this. But you can ask a new question with new requirements.